# How to enable Implicit grant in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access ***Microsoft Graph*** using ***the implicit flow***, after successful authentication with Azure Active Directory.

I granted access to `Read directory data`. However, my implicit flow still doesn't work, although user is authenticated successful.

[image]

According to [v2.0 Protocols - SPAs using the implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit#send-the-sign-in-request), I need to enable *Implicit grant*. ***I'm wondering where and how I enable Implicit grant***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case,If you want to access Microsoft Graph API, you need to add it in Required permissions.
[image]

> I'm wondering where and how I enable Implicit grant.

You can open the **Manifest** of your AAD Application and Edit it.

You can enable the implicit flow by changing the `"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false` to be `"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true`

[image]

Comment: It is set as true - `"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true`

Comment: Hi @Win .This action can just enable implicit flow.  Are there some errors you got? You can post more detials about your issue.

Comment: Hi @Win, I saw that you want to access Microsoft Graph, But the screeshot you post is Azure AD Graph API. Could you tell me which API do you want to access ? If you want to access Microsoft Graph API, you need to add it .

Comment: Could you show me how to add access to Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Hi @Win, Find your AAD app> settings > Required permissions > Add > select an API > choose Microsoft Graph > Select> choose required permssions > Save > grant permissions. I also updated my answer.:-)

Comment: I just want to read user's associated Active Directory Group. What access should I choose?

Comment: @Win You need to add `Group.Read.All` permission  which display name is `Read all groups`. You can see this permission in this documentation:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#group-permissions

Comment: Also, I'm not 100 % sure this permission is enough. Feel free to let me know the result. You also may add `Directory.Read.All` permission. Also remember to do grant permissions .:-)